# How to output ACF PRO value to WordPress shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I would like to create a repeater field that has a WooCommerce shortcode in it, and I would like to change the parameters in that shortcode via ACF PRO to be more customizable and for some reason it does not outputting it to the shortcode, but the rest of the repeater works just fine.

Here is my code:

```
<?php if( have_rows('product_category') ): ?>

    <div class="kategorie">

        <?php while( have_rows('product_category') ): the_row();

            // Variables
            $categoryname = get_sub_field('category_name');
            $categoryslug = get_sub_field('category_slug');
            $orderby = get_sub_field('order_by');
            $onsale = get_sub_field('on_sale');
            $columns = get_sub_field('columns');
            $rows = get_sub_field('rows');
        ?>

            <span class="category-header"><?php echo $categoryname; ?></span>

            <?php echo do_shortcode("[product_category category=\"<?php echo $categoryslug; ?>\" per_page=\"<?php echo $columns; ?>\" columns=\"<?php echo $rows; ?>\" orderby=\"<?php echo $orderby; ?>\" order=\"desc\" operator=\"AND\" on_sale=\"<?php echo $onsale; ?>\"]"); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>

  <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: you need a string concatenation, try that `<?php echo do_shortcode("[product_category category=\"$categoryslug\" per_page=\"$collums\" columns=\"$rows\" orderby=\"$orderby\" order=\"desc\" operator=\"AND\" on_sale=\"$onsale\"]");?>`

Comment: Thanks you are great it helped me a lot !